# How to assign all non-zero elements in each numpy column to a value in an array whose size is the same as the number of columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So that's a bit of a mouthful. But here's what I'm looking to do:

```
b = np.array([7,8,2,3])

a = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 1, 0]])

*** The Magic Happens ***

array([[7, 8, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 2, 3],
       [0, 8, 2, 0]])
```

Comment: Is `a` always ones and zeros?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I have a feeling it won't matter. But you can assume as much

Comment: Well, if it's always 1 and 0, you can just use `a*b` which will (magically) broadcast. In fact, even if it's not: `(a > 0) * b` works too.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Good thinking! I'm going to leave the question open just incase there's a more general way. But thank you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hardly think there is a faster/neater answer for this. Writing for others to find it helpful. As @Mark mentioned in the comments, you can find non-zero elements by `a>0` and multiplying it into `b` will broadcast `b` to `a`'s shape by repeating rows and multiply element-wise:

```
output = (a > 0) * b
```

Another way would be:

```
a[a>0] = np.tile(b,(a.shape[0],1))[a>0]
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see which one is faster: `(a > 0) * b` or `a.astype(bool) * b`.

Comment: @Guimoute I would expect them to be about the same. I do not see why one would have advantage over the other. `a.astype()` creates a copy and if `a` is large might not be beneficial.